# Does Caliburn.Micro have a naming convention to bind a property to ComboBox Text?

Tags: caliburn.micro

In my View I have a combobox named Servers. In my ViewModel I have property called Servers that returns a collection of server names, and a SelectedServer to hold the selection.

BUT the combobox has IsEditable set to true in case someone wants to use a server that's not in the list. Typing a server name into the combobox does not put the entered text into the SelectedServer property. Is there a standard naming convention that Caliburn.Micro will use to bind the to Text property of the ComboBox?

I already know how to create my own bindings to do this, and I have done that, so please no answers that say:

```
<ComboBox Name="Servers"
          Text="{Binding Path=SelectedServer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True"/>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can just name the property in my ViewModel to something else to have it bind to the ComboBox's Text instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: I think it is possible, but only if you [add a custom convention](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Not built in as far as I am aware, by default the convention is to bind to the selected item. The two options you have are:

1. Write a new convention to do it for you
2. Do it manually as you say above